# R - Parsing the un-evaluated value of an argument after 2 calls

Tags: r

I'm trying to parse un-evaluated value of an argument of a function which itself is given as argument to the calling function.

```
f1 <- function(arg){
  f2(arg)
}
f2 <- function(arg2){
  print(deparse(substitute(arg2)))
}

f1(sometext)
```

I would like to use `sometext` inside the f2 function as string by deparsing and/or using it as variable by enquo-ing it.

If I parse is this way it just gives the name from the calling environment. I need it to give the name `something`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to (or are not able to) modify `f1()` you can use `lazyeval::expr_find()` as a replacement for the `substitute()`. It will find the original expression through the call stack.

```r
f1 <- function(arg) {
  f2(arg)
}

f2 <- function(arg2) {
  deparse(lazyeval::expr_find(arg2))
}

f1(sometext)
#> [1] "sometext"
```

Created on 2018-08-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thanks alot, this is what I was originally looking for, as it works for any arbitrary number of nested calls.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I found the way. Just mentioning it here if anyone else encounters the same problem.
The solution is to substitute the value when calling the second function.

`f2(substitute(arg))`

This way only the name that is given the first function is passed to the second.

The code is as follows.

```
f1 <- function(arg){
  f2(substitute(arg))
}
f2 <- function(arg2){
  print(arg2)
}

f1(sometext)'
```

Comment: The response of `f1(sometext)`, is `sometext` and not your favorit answer

Comment: Actually, we could just `deparse` it to get what I originally mentioned in the comment.

Comment: *in the question